# Create the same post in multiple directories

Tags: jekyll

I have a post (created with [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/)) in a directory that I use as whitepapers and I want the post to be also put under a blog.  Is it possible to have a generator put them in both locations?

Comment: copy/paste the file or create a symlink in the _posts directory?

Comment: Why down-voting this question ? Even if it's a little to short, the topic is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Before thinking of duplicating, maybe you can use tags.

- One menu will use the **whitepaper** tag to list whitepapers.
- Other menu will list all posts

Post's front matter:

```
---
layout: post
title: my post
tags : [ whitepaper ]
----
```

Whitepapers menu :

```
<ul>
  {% for p in site.posts %}
    {% if p.tags contains 'whitepaper' %}
    <li><a href="{{ p.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ p.title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Blog menu :

```
<ul>
  {% for p in site.posts %}
    <li><a href="{{ p.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ p.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

No plugin, no duplicate content (think SEO). Nice !

But if you really need to duplicate, you'll have to go with a generator plugin.
You can find links to some examples in [Jekyll's documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators-1).

Answer (score 0):

When you do not have problems using a plug-ins. Have a look to:
[Jekyll PlugIn Redirect-From](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from)

Example from your `post.md`, permalink is not needed, just use **redirect_from**

```
title: My post with more then one URL
permalink: /myPost/
redirect_from:
  - /myPostt/
  - /post/somefolder/wrongName/
```

We have an redirect from the typo `myProstt` and from an other folder / url.